# swift when static variable was released

Tags: swift

I want to know when `static` variable will be released, so i create like below:

```
class A {
    init() {
        print("A init")
    }

    deinit {
        print("A deinit")
    }
}

class B {
    static let a = A()

    deinit {
        print("B deinit")
    }

    init() {
        print("B init")
    }
}

var b: B? = B()
B.a
b = nil
```

When variable `a`'s `deinit` was called? If `b = nil` then `A`'s `deinit` wasn't called.

Comment: never? it is singleton realization.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Objects will only be deinitialized when nothing else is holding a strong reference to it.

In your case, `b` is *not* holding a reference to `a`. The class `B` *is*.

Setting `b` to nil does not do anything to `a` because `b` never ever held a reference to `a`. `b` is essentially irrelevant. `a` and `b` are non-related objects.

Now that we know the *class* `B` is holding a reference to `a`, can we somehow destroy the class `B` so that `a` can be deinitialised? The answer is no. `a` is like a variable in the global scope. `a` will only be deinitialised when the program stops.

Another way to make something get deinitialised is by setting all the references to it to refer to something else. But since in this case `a` is declared with `let`, you can't really change it.

Answer (score 2):

First, of all When you define static properties and method into a class (or struct), those variables are kept in the *Permanent Generation area*. and it will be shared among all the instances (or values).

This will be released by two ways:

> 1: When the classes are released but it is impossible to see Because
>   Classes are going in a special area on the heap: Permanent Generation
>   and  when the application will terminate classes will be released
>
> 2: You can assign nil forcibly like this

```
class A {
    init() {
        print("A init")
    }

    deinit {
        print("A deinit")
    }
}

class B {
    static var a:A? = A()

    deinit {
        print("B deinit")

    }

    init() {
        print("B init")
    }
    static func call(){
        a = nil
    }
}

var b: B? = B()
B.a
B.call() //forcely call 
b = nil
```

**Output**

```
B init
A init
B deinit
A deinit
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that `b` is `nil`. This does not change `B.a` because `a` is a static member. In your example, `a` is not deinitialised. If you want the `deinit` to be called, you have to assign a new object to `B.a`. However, B.a is a constant (`let`). You can change it to `var`, otherwise this particular object will never be deinitialized.

```
class B {
    static var a = A()
    \\ ...
}

B.a = A() //deinit of the old `B.a` is called
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it won't since B has a strong reference of A, but you could make something like: `static weak var a = A()` on your B class. And when B = nil, it will call the deinit of A and then deinit of B.