# When static object auto release in singleton pattern in iOS?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, memory-management, static, singleton

I have a question about singleton using static memory.
I usually use this pattern to hold my temporary data in my APP.
When I leave the APP for a long time, is it possible that the singletion memory will be automatically released, and my temporary data will be gone?
If the memory is released, when is it released?
I would like to know the safety and is there any chance of this happening.

```
class TestObject: NSObject {
    
    static let sharedInstance = TestObject()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static variables in Swift are initialized when first accessed and never released. See [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108739/how-is-life-cycle-of-static-var) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956851/swift-when-static-variable-was-released) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69363771/what-is-the-lifespan-of-a-static-variable-in-swift) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988603/what-will-be-life-time-of-a-class-if-it-is-containing-any-static-variable-and-st). That is, they live while your app lives.

The app lifecycle is another topic and you can address to [this official source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle) as a start.

So, if you're OK that your variable is lazily initialized on first access and re-initialized from scratch on app launch, you're safe enough. If your variable should store data across app launches (which is impossible in principle for any variable), think about saving data somewhere, disk or something.